# The textfield cursor does not work correctly

Tags: flutter

The textfield cursor does not work correctly when I retrieve data from the database and display it in a textfield and then try to edit it.

I would like the position of the cursor to be respected each time I return the validate result of the change method.

[image: How its working]

Full code below.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TextField Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  ApplicationBloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = new ApplicationBloc();
    _bloc.initData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextField Test'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[_buildName(), _buildEmail(), _buildSubmit()],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildName() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.name,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          _nameController.text = snapshot.data;
        }
        return TextField(
          controller: _nameController,
          onChanged: _bloc.changeName,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Name",
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEmail() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.email,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          _emailController.text = snapshot.data;
        }
        return TextField(
          controller: _emailController,
          onChanged: _bloc.changeEmail,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Email",
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSubmit() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.submit,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data)
              ? null
              : () {
                  _bloc.submitForm();
                  _nameController.text = '';
                  _emailController.text = '';
                },
          child: Text('Submit!'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ApplicationBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<String> _nameController =
      BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: '');
  Observable<String> get name => _nameController.stream.transform(validateName);
  Function(String) get changeName => _nameController.sink.add;

  BehaviorSubject<String> _emailController =
      BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: '');
  Observable<String> get email =>
      _emailController.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;

  Observable<bool> get submit => Observable.combineLatest2(
      name, email, (e, e1) => e.isNotEmpty && e1.isNotEmpty);

  initData() {
    // This data from database
    _nameController.sink.add('Test123');
    _emailController.sink.add('test@email.com');
  }    

  submitForm() {
    //Send to api and wait
    //Reset values
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  final validateName =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (name, sink) {
    if (name.isEmpty || name.length > 4) {
      sink.add(name);
    } else if (name.isNotEmpty) {
      sink.addError('Invalid Name!');
    }
  });

  final validateEmail =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
    String p =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';

    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);
    if (email.isEmpty || (email.length > 4 && regExp.hasMatch(email))) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Invalid email!');
    }
  });

  //dispose/close all the streams when we call dispose() method
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.close();
    _emailController.close();
  }
}
```

I tried a code that changes the cursor position to final but its not work properly when i try edit the middle content of the textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the `text` setter of `TextEditingController`, you'll see:

```dart
set text(String newText) {
  value = value.copyWith(
    text: newText,
    selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: -1),
    composing: TextRange.empty,
  );
}
```

Notice that `selection` is reset, so you cannot use this setter. Instead, inside your builder, do:

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  _nameController.value = _nameController.value.copyWith(
    text: snapshot.data,
  );
}
```

Just the text is going to change and you don't have to worry about the other properties.